# Find Out if Content Active in jQuery Accordion on change event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

So, I've got a jQuery accordion, and in the content areas I've created some pseudo checkboxes using images. This works fine in all browsers but IE 6/7 (which unfortunately, I have to support). What happens is when I toggle closed/open a section, the checkboxes appear before the content is completely opened via the animation. One option is to disable animations for IE, but I'd prefer not to do that. Instead, I was hoping there was a way I could show/hide checkboxes via the change/changestart function. However, it seems to do this, I need to find out in the changestart function if the content is about to expand, or about to collapse. If its collapsing, I'll need to hide the checkboxes before the animation begins. Likewise, in the change function (the one executed upon completion), I'll need to see if the content was opened or closed. If it was opened, then we'll want to show the checkboxes inside it. Here's what I'm trying now, but all its able to do is hide it, and it always does, so I'm thinking basing it on the .ui-accordion-content-active class isn't going to work:

```
$("#filter_accordion").accordion({
    header: "> div > h3",
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.newContent.hasClass(".ui-accordion-content-active")) ui.newContent.find(".checkbox").show();
    },
    changestart: function(event, ui) {
      if (!(ui.newContent.hasClass(".ui-accordion-content-active"))) ui.newContent.find(".checkbox").hide();
    }
  });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, never got any responses to this, but in case anyone else runs across it, I found a solution. The visibility of the UI icon has to do with another IE bug of shifting the icons around vertically when expanding/collapsing sections. ie67 is just a boolean set in my template describing if we're using one of those browsers (IE 6/7), in case that's not obvious.

```
$("#filter_accordion").accordion({
    header: "> div > h3",
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    changestart: function(event, ui) {
      if (ie67) {
        $("#filter_accordion .ui-icon").css("visibility", "hidden");
        ui.oldContent.find(".checkbox").hide();
        if (ui.newContent.is(":visible")) ui.newContent.find(".checkbox").hide();
      }
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
      if (ie67) {
        $("#filter_accordion .ui-icon").css("visibility", "visible");
        if (ui.newContent.is(":visible")) ui.newContent.find(".checkbox").show();
      }
    }
  });
```